# How do I combine two signals on one XY plot?

Tags: c#, wpf

The .xaml code:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
  <Canvas x:Name="gCanvasPlot0" Width="500" Height="150" ... />
</Grid>
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
  <Canvas x:Name="gCanvasPlot1" Width="500" Height="150" ... />
</Grid>
```

The .cs code:

```
//------------------------------
...
Plot(gCanvasPlot0, gpoXY0, glistdParams0, glistPoints0);
Plot(gCanvasPlot1, gpoXY1, glistdParams1, glistPoints1);
//------------------------------
//------------------------------
private void Plot(Canvas canvas, Polyline poXY, List<double> listdParams, List<Point> listPoints)
{
  int iii = 0;
  int iNumOfPoints = (int)listdParams[iii++];
  double dXmin = listdParams[iii++];
  double dXmax = listdParams[iii++];
  double dYmin = listdParams[iii++];
  double dYmax = listdParams[iii++];

  double dPlotWidth = dXmax - dXmin;
  double dPlotHeight = dYmax - dYmin;

  for (int ii = 0; ii < iNumOfPoints; ii++) {
    var pointResult = new Point {
      X = (listPoints[ii].X - dXmin) * canvas.Width / dPlotWidth,
      Y = canvas.Height - (listPoints[ii].Y - dYmin) * canvas.Height / dPlotHeight };
    poXY.Points.Add(pointResult);
  }
  canvas.Children.Add(poXY);
}//Plot
//------------------------------
```

This code works well to create two XY plots.  I want to put both signals on one XY plot.  How do I combine two signals on one XY plot?

Comment: remove gCanvasPlot1 and use only gCanvasPlot0?

Answer (score -3):

[ASh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1506454/ash) was correct with [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69898950/how-do-i-combine-two-signals-on-one-xy-plot/69899239#comment123559623_69898950) suggesting the removal of `gCanvasPlot1` and only using `gCanvasPlot0`.